# How can I generate a random dataset in approximately equal proportions

Tags: python

How can I generate a random dataset with 8 columns and 50,000 rows. Each column must be a categorical variable (breed of dog) with 3 levels (example, colour), resulting in approximately equal proportions using Python. How many unique rows (i.e., permutations of category levels) are possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = np.empty(50000, 8)
data[:,0] = [np.random.choice(col0_options) for i in range(50000)]
# do this for all columns ...
data[:,7] = [np.random.choice(col7_options) for i in range(50000)]
```

If you want to make it less hardcoded you could store every list of options in a dict like `{0: col0_options, ..., 7: col7_options}` and then do:

```
options = {0: col0_options, ..., 7: col7_options}
data = np.empty(50000, 8)
for i in range(8):
    data[:,i] = [np.random.choice(options[i]) for i in range(50000)]
```

Since there are 8 cols and 3 values per col there are 3^8 unique possibilities.